# Windows Workflow Foundation - get list of executed activities?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Is there a way to get the list of executed activites in a windows workflow? I have one that has several paths, and i want to access from outside after they've been executed (from a test) which activities where executed, but i don't find anything that has that. Does it exist? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create your own TrackingParticipant and you can see what is executing in your workflow.